# How to Disable right click both mouse and keyboard in MIcrosoft Edge

Tags: javascript, if-statement, microsoft-edge

Disable right click in Microsoft Edge.This below code works fine in Google and Internet Explorer
 
        document.onmousedown = clickfn;

```
    function clickfn(e) {
        var button;
        if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            button = event.button;

        }
        else {
            button = e.buttons;
        }

        if (button == 2) {
            alert("Right Click Disabled");

            if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
                event.returnValue = false;
            }                
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to disable right-click? That's not very user friendly.

Comment: In my scenario am displaying a PDF doc to user.I don't want user to SaveAs the doc by using right click from mouse or keyboard.I found the code to disable right click in Google and IE.But its not working in Microsoft Edge

Comment: @K.HariHaran Why are you forcing the user to have to go into the developer tools just to download the PDF? That's not very user-friendly.

Comment: I just want to disable the right click in Microsoft Edge,Google,IE inside my C# project only.@phihag

Comment: Both Chrome and Firefox have ways to break your current solution; either through a setting or an extension. If you want to apply some sort of DRM on the PDF file look into doing that.

Comment: oncontextmenu="return false;"

Answer (score 0):

This code will disable mouse right-click and keyboard shortcuts as well in IE,edge,chrome,firefox

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function disableSelection(e) {
        if (typeof e.onselectstart != "undefined") e.onselectstart = function() {
            return false
        };
        else if (typeof e.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") e.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
        else e.onmousedown = function() {
            return false
        };
        e.style.cursor = "default"
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        disableSelection(document.body)
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 65 || e.which == 66 || e.which == 67 || e.which == 70 || e.which == 73 || e.which == 80 || e.which == 83 || e.which == 85 || e.which == 86)) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    });
    document.keypress = function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 65 || e.which == 66 || e.which == 70 || e.which == 67 || e.which == 73 || e.which == 80 || e.which == 83 || e.which == 85 || e.which == 86)) {}
        return false
    };

    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == 123 || e.keyCode == 18) {
            return false
        }
    };

    document.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
        var t = e || window.event;
        var n = t.target || t.srcElement;
        if (n.nodeName != "A") return false
    };
    document.ondragstart = function() {
        return false
    };
});
```